# Where are all the diamonds?

Tags: recursed

In Recursed,

> causing a paradox leads to a secret room where a diamond can be earned.

**Which levels have diamonds?**

I'm not interested in how to get them, just which levels have them.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Alright, adapted from [this guide](https://steamcommunity.com/sharedfiles/filedetails/?id=816999049):

---

There is a hint in-game about the diamond locations.  In

> The Void - Payload

on one of the walls there is

> 0003322

this is

> the number of diamonds in each chapter

---

If that's not enough, here are the specific levels with diamonds.

- Dungeon

  - Sluice
  - Attic
  - Obstruction
- Ruins

  - Feedback
  - Embed
  - Interlock
- Temple

  - Clasp
  - Blister
- The Void

  - Escalate
  - Trilemma